# Debug golang program that requires dedicated terminal

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code

Golang: 1.15
Visual Studio Code: 1.49.1

The Go program is rendering a Console User Interfaces with [gocui](https://github.com/jroimartin/gocui), and requires a dedicated terminal to run correctly.

Q: how to build the program, start it up in a terminal and debug it with the VSC?

Comment: from the author of the post: before you downvote, could you add a comment why is this post wrong? I have spend close to a working day trying to make Golang "attach" debug work for me, and the only thing i am persuading is sharing my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Build the program with [debug flags](https://golang.org/cmd/compile/):

   ```
   go build -gcflags="all=-N -l" -o $(BUILD_PATH)
   ```
2. Add following configuration to your VSC:

   ```
       {
           "name": "Connect to dlv server",
           "type": "go",
           "request": "attach",
           "mode": "remote",
           "remotePath": "${workspaceFolder}",
           "port": 2345,
           "host": "127.0.0.1"
       },
   ```
3. Start up the compiled program via debugger
   *NOTE:* `dlv` is an official Go debugger, installed along with the Go SDK

   ```
   dlv --listen=:2345 --headless=true --api-version=2 --accept-multiclient exec {YOUR_PROGRAM}
   ```
4. Chose "Connect to dlv server" from the Debug view and happy debugging!